# Using Webpack for browser extension problems accessing DOM elements of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, webpack, dom

I'm creating a browser extension for firefox and originally had an issue about using `require()` statements in JS. I fixed this issue using Webpack to bundle the code and give me access to those statements. I am now having an issue with trying to use `document.getElementByID` selectors for the DOM elements. I cannot seem to access these elements at all.

My JS code looks like this:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {

    const button = document.getElementById('#spellButton');
    button.addEventListener("click", function () {
        const paragraph = document.getElementById("spellResult");
        paragraph.textContent = "Hello!";
    });

});
```

My HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="popup.css">

  <script src="main.js" type="module"></script>

  <title>Document</title>


</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <p>
      Site Spy
    </p>
  </header>

  <main class="safteyCheck">
    <u>
      Current Site:
    </u>
    <p id="siteURL"> a</p>
    <p style="color: grey;" id="result">
      UNKOWN
    </p>
    <button id="scanButton">
      Scan Site
    </button>
    <p id="spellResult"></p>
    <button id="spellButton">
      Scan Site
    </button>

  </main>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; 2023 EggsCorp</p>
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "webpack-demo",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webpack-cli/generators": "^3.0.7",
    "webpack": "^5.89.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.1.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "typo-js": "^1.2.3"
  }
}
```

I am new to webpack & extension development so forigve me if there is an obvious error, I cannot figure this out at the moment. What could the issue be or a work around?

I expected to be able to use DOM elements in Webpack but have possibly misunderstood what I need to do.